# Voice dictation repeats whole sentences in a big garbled chunk on Mac OS X High Sierra

Tags: macos, high-sierra, voice-dictation

**Problem:**
During macOS dictation, it sometimes repeat-types the sentence I have spoken multiple times in a row.  This seems to happen randomly.  Sometimes every minute or two, sometimes taking up to 20 minutes between occurrences.

**Example:**

1. I said: **I'm using Mac OS 10 dictation for this, and I'm very
   impressed with the quality *period* I had to fiddle with the settings to get it to work right at first *period***
2. The computer immediately output an entire paragraph of garbled repeats of those sentences.  See the results below:

*I'm using Mac OS 10 dictation for this, and I'm very impressed with the quality. I hdI'm very impressed with the quality. and iI'm very impressed with the quality. Ifor ovI'm very impressed with the quality. I hfor ovI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with thi setting tI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to wtI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to wortI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to work tI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to work ritI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to work rightI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to work righI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to work rhI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get to workhI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get ito work rI'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get it to work r I'm very impressed with the quality. I had to fiddle with the settings to get it to work right at first.*

Troubleshooting so far:

- Quit all other apps that might be using the microphone
- Turned off advanced dictation commands
- turned dictation on and off
- Turned off "Enabled dictation keyword phrase"
- Turned off "paste that" and "Copy that" dictation commands
- Searched the web for others with this problem
- Searched Ask Different for this problem in the past
- Searched apple support site for dictation support articles (they have deleted all High Sierra support articles)

I'm using Mac OS X High Sierra 10.13.6, Enhanced Dictation is on, Language is English (United States) on a MacBook Pro 15" Retina mid-2015.  Application is Day One Journal.  I just turned on dictation and this immediately started happening.

Thank you!

P.S. With great irony, I thought the problem was solved after 20 minutes of it not happening, and I tried to tell my journal I was happy about solving it. That really is the single sentence I tried to dictate, and it immediately spewed all that out.

Comment: Have you tested in another app, TextEdit etc, to eliminate it being a single app with the issue?